# Expanding or collapsing last FAQ section

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, meta-faq

Expanding or collapsing the last section of the FAQ ("How do I search?") sends you back up to the top of the page, while the other sections expand nicely without jumping around the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there are two HTML tags that use the same CSS ID ("search").
This should be fixed the next time they deploy.

[Jeff Atwood's answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/when-i-click-on-the-how-do-i-search-header-the-browser-shows-me-the-top-of-th/1814#1814) to [my question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/when-i-click-on-the-how-do-i-search-header-the-browser-shows-me-the-top-of-th) is  the following one:

> We have
>
> ```
> id="search"
> ```
>
> there and also in the header. I changed it so it will now be
>
> https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#searching
>
> instead of
>
> https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#search

The revision for which I reported the bug is 2011.8.24.3; until the revision is that, the issue should still be present.